# Smallest pairs to be added to a set to make it an equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

$$R = \{(1,1), (1,3), (1,5), (4,4),(4,6)\}, \quad A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

> Determine the smallest set of pairs of elements which needs to be added to $R$ so that the resulting relation $\Bbb{R}^*$ is an equivalance relation.

**My atttempt:**

In order for it to equivalent relation it needs to be reflective, symmetric and transitive.

This would mean that the lowest reflective pair is $(1,1)$ which is already in $\Bbb{R}$.

There seem to be no transitive pairs within $\Bbb{R}$ and no symmetric pairs either.

**Question:** I am wondering how would this solved as I assumed you would write out all the other pairs that are not in $\Bbb{R}$ which would make up $\Bbb{R}^*$.

Comment: A relation R on a set A is called reflexive if and only if (a, a) $\in$  R for every element a of A. 
You need to add reflexive pairs for rest of the elements of the set.
$(1,5)$ is in R so its symmetric pair should be added which is $(5,1)$
Check symmetric property for every element of R. Then check for transitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think about this in terms of equivalence classes, rather than an equivalence relation: what is the most fine-grained partition of $A$ into equivalence classes that $R$ "allows"?

For instance, letting $A$ have only one equivalence class would be allowed by $R$, but it's probably not the most fine-grained. On the other hand, letting each element be alone in its own equivalence class is the most fine-grained you can get, but it is not allowed by $R$. You need to find the middle gound here.

Once you have the equivalence classes, you can find the corresponding equivalence relation, and figure out which pairs are in there.

Comment: To add to your fine answer, each element should be related to as few other elements as possible. In fact one can draw a graph using the edges found in $R$ and then recognize the components of this graph as the equivalence classes.

Comment: @String "each element should be related to as few other elements as possible" That's why I stressed "fine-grained" partitions. It might not be conventional terminology, but I like it.

Comment: I realized that and wanted to crystalize that idea further. To make it more clear that this would imply fewest relations, I mean. Fine-grained does not quite as intuitively point to that effect, I think.

Answer (score 0):

> This would mean that the lowest reflective pair is $(1,1)$ which is already in 
>   R.

You need to *add* the *least amount* of pairs *needed* to *make* $R^\ast$ reflexive.   Merely having $(1,1)$ will *not* make $R^\ast$ reflexive, on its own.   Some new pairs will need to be *added.*

To be reflexive will require that $\forall x\in A: (x,x)\in R^\ast$, what is, for every element $x$ in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ the pair $(x,x)$ needs to be in $R^\ast$.   So what pairs need to be added to make this so?

> There seem to be no transitive pairs within $R$ and no symmetric pairs either.

Indeed, that is why they need to be *added*.   Your task is to add the *fewest necessary* pairs to make $R^\ast$ transitive and symmetric.   (PS: remember the pairs added above will still be needed to be in $R^\ast$.)

Start with symmetry.